# Quantifier {x,y} following nothing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have exception like this when i try to validate email and phone number on my Program.

Error: The regex was wrote correctly and I don't know where is problem.

I read the last post but any work in my case.

> Message: System.ArgumentException : parsing '{2}[0-9]-{3}[0-9]' - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.

```
public class Order
{
    public string EmailValidationPattern = "{2}[0-9]-{3}[0-9]";

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    private void SetZipCode(string zipCode)
    {
        if (Regex.Match(zipCode, EmailValidationPattern).Success)
        {
            ZipCode = zipCode;
        }
    }

    private void SetPhoneNumber(string number)
    {
        if (Regex.Match(number, @"^(\+[0-9]{9})$").Success)
        {
            PhoneNumber = number;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `{2}` must be preceded by something. Maybe you meant `[0-9]{2}`?

Comment: The regex was not "wrote correctly" and that's why there is an error.

Comment: "Error: The regex was wrote correctly and I don't know where is problem." What? There is no such error. 
"I read the last post but any work in my case." your question is quite unclear and badly worded. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is strange that you call the variable `EmailValidationPattern` and use it exactly for _not_ validating an email address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace
`{2}[0-9]-{3}[0-9]`
with
`[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}`

The quantifier comes *after* the expression to be matched.  [0-9]{3}

Also, you can test your expression online with something like http://regexstorm.net/tester

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to accomplish but it looks like you're looking for numeric characters only...

For numeric only:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d$");
```

For alphanumeric:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
```